# How to refresh excel file on a machine which doesn't have Microsoft excel installed (Python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have this excel file which is of around 37MB. I am reading the file `pd.read_excel()` and update specific sheets of the excel with **openpyxl** and write back. Once it is written, the file size reduces to 16MB. The file contains functions in some of the sheets. But, when the file is updated once, I am unable to read the values from the sheets which I read values earlier. I think, this is because the functions do not get updated after the write. If, I open the file and save the file again, the values are readable.

I have been looking for methods to refresh the excel file after write. But, all the methods found requires excel installed in the machine. Would like to know whether there is a way **we can refresh an excel file without opening the file with python**.

I am updating the file as follows:

```
        # new dataframe with same columns
        df = data_frame
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(folder_path, engine='openpyxl')
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = op.load_workbook(folder_path)
        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
        # read existing file
        reader = pd.read_excel(folder_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        reader = reader.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
        # write out to the sheet
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader) + 2)
        writer.save()
```

Comment: How are you saving it after you've updated it?

Comment: Updated my question..:/ Think I am doing two reads as well.

Comment: Using `with` is strongly encouraged with `ExcelWriter` for example: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

`ExcelWriter` takes "Path to xls or xlsx file." as first argument not folder.

```
pd.ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Actually, I just sent the code fragment inside my method. It is the file path that I am passing to pd.ExcelWriter.